# Adding dropbox to my ios app

Tags: ios

I am adding Dropbox support to my iOS application. Using the official Dropbox API and the tutorials  [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#ios) .And, once authenticated, How can I save a file present in my dropbox to the user's Dropbox??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if I get it right, then there are two possible solutions.

**OPTION 1**  (easiest and guaranteed to work)
Easiest solution is to make a share link of the file you want to download from your drobox.
In the app then send a request and download the file using the link.
After that, use the methods from dropbox tutorial to upload the file to the user's dropbox.

**OPTION 2**  (faster, better)
Use copy_ref to just copy a reference to the file between two accounts, instead of downloading and reuploading. Look at this entry in Dropbox API - https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#copy_ref

Comment: Thank u very much for your reply.....considering first option if i have a directory that contain images in it.When i share it i got a link using ASIHTTPRequest i downloaded that ..do i need to parse that ???

Comment: yeah found the solution .........thanks